# Rails 4: can a child model belong_to two different parent models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, activerecord, relational-database

In my initial Rails 4 app, I had the following models:

```
User
has_many :administrations
has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
has_many :comments

Calendar
has_many :administrations
has_many :users, through: :administrations
has_many :posts
has_many :comments, through: :posts

Administration
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :calendar

Post
belongs_to :calendar
has_many :comments

Comment
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

I just added a new `Ad` model to the app:

```
Ad
belongs_to :calendar
```

And now I would like to allow users to write comments about the ad records.

Can I use my existing `Comment` model and do something like:

```
Ad
belongs_to :calendar
has_many :comments

Comment
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

Or do I need to create a distinct "Comment" model, that I would call for instance `AdComments` or `Feedback`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Something on the lines of this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

And the migration would look like:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I guess you already have the comments table, so you should rather change the table with

```
class ChangeComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :comments do |t|
      t.rename :post_id, :commentable_id 
      t.string :commentable_type, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Also beware, that if you have live data you should update the `commentable_type` field of all already existing comments to `Post`. You can either do it in a migration or from the console.

```
Comment.update_all commentable_type: 'Post'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I agree with what you recommend for the models (that's what I have already implemented actually). However, I am not sure I am following what you say about migrations. I do have the comment table, so I want to change it (not to create it) but I don't understand the line `t.string commentable_type, null: false` since what I am trying to do is `t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true, index: true` as recommended here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Also, how can I update the `commentable_type` field of all already existing comments to `Post`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I had a wrong assumption there. You should remove the `post_id` from the table and use `t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true, index: true` just as you said. I will fix the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I guess the correct migration will be something like: `class AddCommentableToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :comments do |t|
      t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true, index: true
    end
  end
end`

Comment: Do you have live data?

Comment: Yes, I do. Would you like to move to chat, it may be easier?

Comment: I have the right amount of info now. If you have live data, then just deleting the `post_id` is not an options. What `t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true` does is that it creates two fields `commentable_id`, and `commentable_type`. The second stores the class name of the associated entity. So I would recommend to rename `post_id` to `commentable_id` to preserve the data and add the second field manually and then you have the DB setup for the polymorphic assoc. I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: That makes complete sense. Only problem, I just got the following error: `PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  column "commentable_type" contains null values`. Should I run the migration without `null: false` first, then run `Comment.update_all commentable_type: 'Post'` and finally add `null: false` with a new migration? Or is there a specific command to apply `null: false` to only new records for instance?

Comment: I have lost my comments in development, but this must be due to the prior (wrong) migrations I ran. In production, it will work. Thanks a lot for everything, this was a great and very useful answer.

Comment: I strongly recommend to rollback, create some comments and migrate again in dev before deployment to avoid data loss. Just in case I was wrong.

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need to use any new model, you can just refactor the current Comment model with [polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

So, a comment always belongs to a user, and belongs to a post or ad

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.