# Rails 4: create action not working in polymorphic association with shallow resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

In my Rails 4 app, I used to have the model architecture described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208331/rails-4-can-a-child-model-belong-to-two-different-parent-models/34209265?noredirect=1#comment56164730_34209265).

For some reasons, I had to create a new `Ad` model and transform the `Comment` model so it has a polymorphic association with the `Ad` and `Post` models, and I now have the following models:

```
User
has_many :administrations
has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
has_many :comments

Calendar
has_many :administrations
has_many :users, through: :administrations
has_many :posts
has_many :comments, through: :posts
has_many :ads
has_many :ads, through: :posts

Administration
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :calendar

Post
belongs_to :calendar
has_many :comments, as: :commentable

Ad
belongs_to :calendar
has_many :comments, as: :commentable

Comment
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :user
```

Here are my routes:

```
resources :calendars do
  resources :posts, shallow: true do
    resources :comments, shallow: true
  end
  resources :ads, shallow: true do
    resources :comments, shallow: true
  end
end
```

Everything was working perfectly before I implemented the polymorphic association.

Now, I am no longer capable of creating comments, neither for `Post` records nor for `Ad` records.

This is my `Comments#Create` action:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:commentable_id])
  @ad = Ad.find(params[:commentable_id])
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to create a new comment, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Post with 'id'=
@post = Post.find(params[:commentable_id])
```

I am obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you still need to setup the polymorphic relationship in your `Comment` model:

```
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
```

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. My `Comment` model is setup like that, I made a mistake when writing the question. I still get the same error.

Comment: OK, good! Then, looking at your code for the create method, it's not clear what `@commentable` is, but you should be able to get a reference to either a post or ad and then build a comment for it, like so: `@post.build_comment(comment_params)`

Comment: Oh and regarding the error you're reporting - looks like the `:commentable_id` param is just an empty string, so it's throwing an error in the `find` method. Make sure something is coming across - you can see what params were received in the Rails log.